# Is there a function for getting the post/page that an attachment is related to?

Tags: attachments

I am working on a custom attachment.php template file for a theme and I want to make it link back to the document that the attachment is included within.

Naturally an attachment may be in multiple documents, but I just wondered if theres a built in or easy way to obtain a list of the posts?

Comment: It's the posts parent

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a built-in way to return all the posts that an attachment is used in.  The closest thing would probably be `$post->post_parent` which all attachments have post parents.

There is a plugin called [Find Posts Using Attachment](https://wordpress.org/plugins/find-posts-using-attachment/) that does a good job of retrieving these and is a single file PHP class so you could possibly repurpose it to obtain the desired result.